# Ordenar os elementos da pilha A e B na pilha C

Tags: c

Estou aprendendo a manipular pilhas na disciplina Estrutura de dados, porém tendo dificuldades na hora de implementar as funções, como a ordenação e o reempilha está apresentando erros no escopo do laço if.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 6

 // Implementando a estrutura
typedef struct
{
       int topo, item[MAX_SIZE];
}stack;

// Função  Inicia Pilha 
void iniciaPilha ( stack *p)
{
     p->topo = -1; // O topo começa em -1,pq em 0 signicaria que estaria já na primeira posição
}

// Função Verifica se a  pilha está Cheia
int pilhaCheia ( stack *p)
{
    if (p->topo == (MAX_SIZE-1))
    {
          printf ("\n\n\t\tA Pilha esta Cheia!!!");
          return 1;
    }else
        return 0;
}

// Função Verifica pilha Vazia 
int pilhaVazia ( stack *p)
{
    if (p->topo == -1)
    {
         printf ("\n\n\t\tA Pilha esta Vazia!!!");
         return 1;
    }
    else
     return 0;
}

//  Função verifica se a 2 está pilha Vazia 
int pilhaVazia2 (stack *p)
{
    if (p->topo == -1) // O topo começa em -1,pq em 0 signicaria que estaria já na primeira posição
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;
}

//   Função Empilha  
int push ( stack *p, int valor)
{
     return (p->item[++(p->topo)] = valor);// retornar ao valor do topo
}

//  Função Desempilha  
int pop ( stack *p)
{
    int aux;
    aux = p->item[(p->topo)--]; //decrementando o topo, ou seja, desempilhando os elementos
    return aux;
}

// Função Mostra Pilha  

int mostra (stack *p)
{
    int aux;
    if (pilhaVazia2 (p))
       return 1;
    else
    {
        aux = pop (p);
        printf ("%d,", aux);
        mostra (p);
        return 0;
    }
}


//  Função reempilha 
int reempilha ( stack *p,  stack *pPilhaB,  stack *pPilhaC)
{
    int aux;
     if (pilhaVazia (p)&&pilhaVazia (pPilhaB))
       return 1;
    else
    {   
       if ((p->item[p->topo]&&(pPilhaB->item[pPilhaB->topo]))//se o topo estiver com uma valor reempilha os valores de A em B
        {
               aux = pop (p)&&pop(pPilhaB);
               push (pPilhaC, aux); 
           //push (pPilhaB, aux);
        }
        reempilha (p, pPilhaB, pPilhaC); // chamando a função para reempilhar os elementos em 
        return 0;
    }

}

// Funcao para pegar os valores a empilhar 
int empilha ( stack *p)
{
    int valor;
    printf ("\n\nInforme os seis valores para ser empilhado ou -2 para mostrar os valores de B  ");
    scanf ("%d",&valor);
    if (pilhaCheia (p))
       return 1;
    else
    {
        if (valor == -2)// se o numero -2 for digitado então os valores impares e pares serão colocados
                  return 0;
        else
        {
            push (p, valor);
empilha (p);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
 int ordenar( stack *p,  stack *pPilhaB,  stack *pPilhaC){
// pilhac=para receber os elementos desempilhados e ordenados   
int aux;//variavel para comparar os elementos

     if (pilhaVazia (p)&&pilhaVazia (pPilhaB))//se a pilha estiver vazia retorno 0, não existe ainda ordenação
       return 0;
      pop (p)&&pop(pPilhaB);// Vou ter que desempilhar um unico elemento de cada pilha

     if ((p->item[p->topo]>=(pPilhaB->item[pPilhaB->topo])) //se o topo estiver com uma valor reempilha os valores de A em B

        {

               aux = pop (p)&&pop(pPilhaB);// aux vai receber os elemntos do topo das duas pilhas

               empilha(pPilhaC); 

        }
        ordenar (p, pPilhaB, pPilhaC); // chamando a função para reempilhar os elementos em 
        return 1;
     }


// Função principal

int main ()
{
   stack pilha, pilha_pPilhaB, pilha_pPilhaC;

   iniciaPilha (&pilha);
   iniciaPilha (&pilha_pPilhaB);
   iniciaPilha (&pilha_pPilhaC);

   push(&pilha, 6);
   push(&pilha, 4);
   push(&pilha, 1);
   printf("\nOs valores  da pilha A = :"); // Mostrando na tela os valores 
   mostra(&pilha);
   printf("\n\n\n");

   push(&pilha_pPilhaB, 5);
   push(&pilha_pPilhaB, 3);
   push(&pilha_pPilhaB, 2);
   printf("\nOs valores  da pilha B = :"); // Mostrando na tela os valores 
   mostra(&pilha_pPilhaB);
   printf("\n\n\n");
    iniciaPilha (&pilha_pPilhaC);
    ordenar ( &pilha,&pilha_pPilhaB,&pilha_pPilhaC);
    printf ("\nOs valores ordenados na pilha C = :"); // Mostrando na tela os valores 
    mostra (&pilha_pPilhaC);


   printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quero saber se a função ordenar está correta, além disso estou tendo dificuldades na função reempilhar

Comment: Josélia, é no corpo da pergunta, não no titulo. Tente responder ao seguinte no corpo da pergunta: 1) O que eu estou tentando fazer? 2) O que eu ja fiz? 3) Qual dificuldade estou tendo?

Comment: A tag está errada, isso não é C#.

Comment: Pronto concertei!!

Comment: Cadê a explicação do problema que você tinha colocado? Estava bom, adicione novamente antes do código.

Answer (score 1):

Segue a solução (testada) do problema utilizando ordenação `bubble sort` não recursiva:

```
/* ****************************************************************** */
/* *                              pilha.c                           * */
/* ****************************************************************** */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define PILHA_MAX_TAM        (10)

#define SUCESSO              (0)
#define ERRO_PILHA_CHEIA     (-1)
#define ERRO_PILHA_VAZIA     (-2)


typedef struct pilha_s pilha_t;

struct pilha_s
{
    int item[ PILHA_MAX_TAM ];
    int qtd;
};


void pilha_inicializar( pilha_t * p )
{
    memset( p, 0, sizeof(pilha_t) );
}


int pilha_push_item( pilha_t * p, int n )
{
    if( p->qtd == PILHA_MAX_TAM )
        return ERRO_PILHA_CHEIA;

    p->item[ p->qtd++ ] = n;

    return SUCESSO;
}


int pilha_push_pilha( pilha_t * pdst, pilha_t * porig )
{
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < porig->qtd; i++ )
        pilha_push_item( pdst, porig->item[i] );

    return SUCESSO;
}


int pilha_pop_item( pilha_t * p )
{
    if( p->qtd == 0 )
        return ERRO_PILHA_VAZIA;

    return p->item[ --p->qtd ];
}


void pilha_listar_itens( pilha_t * p )
{
    int i = 0;

    if( !p->qtd )
    {
        printf("Pilha Vazia!\n");
        return;
    }

    printf( "Pilha:\n" );

    for( i = p->qtd - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        printf( "   Posicao %d / Valor: %d\n", i, p->item[i] );
}


void pilha_ordenar_itens( pilha_t * p )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < p->qtd; i++ )
    {
        for( j = i + 1; j < p->qtd; j++ )
        {
            if( p->item[i] > p->item[j] )
            {
                int aux = p->item[i];
                p->item[i] = p->item[j];
                p->item[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    pilha_t pa;
    pilha_t pb;
    pilha_t pc;

    pilha_inicializar( &pa );
    pilha_inicializar( &pb );
    pilha_inicializar( &pc );

    pilha_push_item( &pa, 6 );
    pilha_push_item( &pa, 4 );
    pilha_push_item( &pa, 1 );

    pilha_listar_itens( &pa );

    pilha_push_item( &pb, 5 );
    pilha_push_item( &pb, 3 );
    pilha_push_item( &pb, 2 );

    pilha_listar_itens( &pb );

    pilha_push_pilha( &pc, &pa );
    pilha_push_pilha( &pc, &pb );

    pilha_listar_itens( &pc );

    pilha_ordenar_itens( &pc );

    pilha_listar_itens( &pc );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Compilando (no Linux):

```
$ gcc -Wall pilha.c -o pilha
```

Saída:

```
$ ./pilha
Pilha:
        Posicao 2 / Valor: 1
        Posicao 1 / Valor: 4
        Posicao 0 / Valor: 6
Pilha:
        Posicao 2 / Valor: 2
        Posicao 1 / Valor: 3
        Posicao 0 / Valor: 5
Pilha:
        Posicao 5 / Valor: 2
        Posicao 4 / Valor: 3
        Posicao 3 / Valor: 5
        Posicao 2 / Valor: 1
        Posicao 1 / Valor: 4
        Posicao 0 / Valor: 6
Pilha:
        Posicao 5 / Valor: 6
        Posicao 4 / Valor: 5
        Posicao 3 / Valor: 4
        Posicao 2 / Valor: 3
        Posicao 1 / Valor: 2
        Posicao 0 / Valor: 1
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Nossa, obrigada

Comment: @JoséliaPires Se a solução atendeu sua pergunta, marque-a como aceita. Obrigado!

Comment: Onde aqui eu marco isto?